# Qt - How to copy file with QFile::copy using QFileDialog?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

```
QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Pdf files"), "C:/", "books(*.pdf)");
```

I want to get the selected file from `QFileDialog` and copy it to my desktop. Can I use something like this?

```
QFile::copy(filename,"desktop");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the path to the desktop using [`QStandardPaths`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html), and then use that path in your call to `QFile::copy`.

Assuming you want to preserve the file name while copying, your code will look something like this:

```
QString filePath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this ,
                                                QObject::tr("Pdf files"),
                                                "C:/", "books(*.pdf)");
QFileInfo fi(filePath);
QString fileName= fi.fileName();
QString desktopPath = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DesktopLocation);
QString destinationPath= desktopPath+QDir::separator()+fileName;
if(QFile::copy(filePath, destinationPath))
    qDebug() << "success";
else
    qDebug() << "failed";
```

Comment: I worked for coping to desktop. If I want to save in another directory, should I change the function QStandardPath?

Comment: your question is unclear, what is the other directory? is it a standard path, or do you have its absolute path?

Comment: Example: If I want to copy to my documents

Comment: Try reading the documentation link in my answer, specifically [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html#StandardLocation-enum). You can use any value you like instead of `QStandardPaths::DesktopLocation`. . .